# How to get all maxes from couchbase using map/reduce?

Tags: view, couchbase

I've got a lot of records like:

```
{
   "id": "1000",
   "lastSeen": "2018-02-26T18:49:21.863Z"
}
{
   "id": "1000",
   "lastSeen": "2017-02-26T18:49:21.863Z"
}
{
   "id": "2000",
   "lastSeen": "2018-02-26T18:49:21.863Z"
}
{
   "id": "2000",
   "lastSeen": "2017-02-26T18:49:21.863Z"
}
```

I'd like to get the most recent records for all ids. So in this case the output would be the following(most recent record for ids 1000 and 2000):

```
{
   "id": "1000",
   "lastSeen": "2018-02-26T18:49:21.863Z"
}

{
   "id": "2000",
   "lastSeen": "2018-02-26T18:49:21.863Z"
}
```

With N1QL, this would be

```
SELECT id, MAX(lastSeen) FROM mybucket GROUP BY id
```

How would I do this using a couchbase view and map/reduce?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am far from a regular user of map/reduce, and there may be more efficient JavaScript, but try this:

Map

```
function (doc, meta) {
  emit(doc.id, doc.lastSeen);
}
```

Reduce

```
function reduce(key, values, rereduce) {
    var max = values.sort().reverse()[0];
    return max;
}
```

Filter: `?limit=6&stale=false&connection_timeout=60000&inclusive_end=true&skip=0&full_set=true&group_level=1`

The idea is to sort all the values being emitted (lastSeen). Since they are ISO 8601 and can be lexigraphically sorted, `sort()` works just fine. You want the latest, so that's what the `reverse()` is for (otherwise you'd get the oldest).

The filter has a group_level of 1, so it will group by the `doc.id` field.

Answer (score 0):

You can query by descending and reduce to first one on list as below:
Map:

```
function (doc, meta) {
  emit(doc.id, doc.lastSeen);
}
```

Reduce:

```
function reduce(key, values, rereduce) {
    return values[0];
}
```

Filter:

```
?inclusive_end=true&skip=0&full_set=&group_level=1&descending=true
```

This will eliminate the overhead of sorting the grouped values inside reduce function.